# Target array shape doesn't match with the shape of the array passed (CNN tensorflow with loss= mean_squared_error`)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss

I'm trying to detect bounding box for paragraph segmentation with CNN . Thats my model ,

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1120, 800, 1)))


model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))



model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

#fit

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_Train ,batch_size=10, epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Shape of x_train shape is (93, 1120, 800, 1) ; y_train is shape is (93,1,4)  .I am following a blog post where they used **MeanSquaredError** as the loss function. Each time I run this code I get this error.

**Error**

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (93, 1, 4) was passed for an output of shape (None, 4) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

I already search for the solution. but didnt find where exactly my problem is.

Comment: Use **tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError** instead of **tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()**

Comment: Does't work . shows  " ValueError: Received uninstantiated Loss class: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError'>
Please call loss ""classes before passing them to Model.compile. "

Comment: Problem Solved .....

Answer (score 0):

Remove the activation='sigmoid'.

MSE is a regression measure while sigmoid is a Classification measure.

```
-MULTI LABEL CLASSIFICATION
activation: sigmoid 
loss: binary_crossentrophy

-MULTI CLASS CLASSIFICATION
activation: softmax
loss: categorical_crossentrophy

REGRESSION (-inf, +inf)
Activation: None
loss: mse
```